# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have Account model that has id, name, timestamps and other fields, I have AccountUser model with account_id and user_id fields, and I have User model with users ids.

I'm trying to get users by account (account has many users) using $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\AccountUser')->get(); but I have an error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.account_user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `account_users`.`account_id` from `users` inner join `account_users` on `account_users`.`id` = `users`.`account_user_id` where `account_users`.`account_id` = 1).

I don't need 'users.account_user_id' column, but it is in query, what to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to define the relationships in the model not in the query .
2. For this case you should use hasOne attribute
3. You have to specify the relationship keys in the model :

```
    // In the User class
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UserAccount::class,'account_id','id');
    }
```

An then call the relationship with

```
$user->account();
```

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) .

Comment: I need users by account, not account by user.

Comment: Same thing , just add in the UserAccount model add `hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');`

Answer (score 0):

hasManyThrough (as all relationship) has a default value, if you don't put nothing in:

```
hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\AccountUser')
```

It gets the default value create from name of Models.

From doc:

> The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of
>   the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the
>   name of the intermediate model.
>
> Typical Eloquent foreign key conventions will be used when performing
>   the relationship's queries. If you would like to customize the keys of
>   the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments
>   to the hasManyThrough method.
>   third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate
>   model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final
>   model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument
>   is the local key of the intermediate model:

See the doc:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I have an error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.account_user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `users`.*, `account_users`.`account_id` from `users` inner join `account_users` on `account_users`.`id` = `users`.`account_user_id` where `account_users`.`account_id` = 1)